# LDO with supercap and diode circuit

Tags: diodes, ldo, supercapacitor

I'm looking for an alternative for a backup battery i'm planning to use.

PCB is powered by 24V DC power supply. I'm using a 3.3V LDO in combination with 3,6V battery to power mcu and other components (~20 mA):

[image: current schematic]

It would be more convenient to use a supercap. The application only needs to run for a couple of seconds (@20mA). I'm worried about inrush current so my proposed solutions would be adding a resistor (1). However this will result in a bigger capacitor. Besides my Vsense line is no longer available to detect lost +24V supply:

[image: LDO with supercap and series resistor]

So what do you think about using a supercap with series resistor (for charging) and a schottky diode for uncharching? +24V supply failure will be detected on the +24v side:

[image]

Comment: why don't you put Vsense on the +24V line if that is what you want to detect failure on?? The LDO output will stay high for a long time due to the battery/supercap.

Comment: @KyranF, that's true. I'll edit my post and remove D3 in the last image. Main question is still regarding charge (through R18) and discharge (through D1) of the supercap. Is that ok with R18 and D1?

Comment: What other power inputs/supplies connect to VDD? Note that the capacitor will still discharge through R18 into VDD, just slower than through D1 - but D1 will drop voltage, so it may be ignored/useless anyway. if you put D1 where you had D3 before, it would work (and stop other supplies connected to VDD from trying to back-charge the capacitor.

Comment: You can also get away with R18 being smaller, like 33 or 22 Ohms if you wanted. Currently 47R at 3.3V will charge the cap at 70mA to begin with

Comment: There are no other power supplies connected to VDD. Just a mcu, some extra ic's (of which a RS485 transceiver ic). So I think there would be no need to put D1 where D3 was. I could simulate how the discharge current through R18 and D1 would go.

Comment: Extra info: there may be up to 20 of these node on a single power line. Problem with the current limiting resistor is that if i use less than 47R (approx) the total startup current would be 20 times the 70mA; thus requiring thicker cables. If i use 47R or more on the other hand, there would be a significant voltage drop over the resistor thereby decreasing efficiency of the capacitor drastically. I might do some more research on a simple supercap charger...

Comment: I've seen supercaps use series resistors before, it's common. The point of supercaps is that they are long-term power, not high-power-power. Also, 47mF isn't really supercap-worthy.. Its on the very low end of what could be considered a supercap, but I guess it still counts. Also what is your linear regulator? Why is it even LDO, if you have such a huge voltage headroom? Why not get a little integrated buck converter + supercap charger IC? Currenlty you have only 13% efficiency, and 87% of energy is lost as heat through the LDO.

Comment: You're right, i'll better use a buck converter. Regarding the supercap I might use a bigger one with just a series resistor,  or a supercap charger. Do you have any references for a simple  charger IC for 3,3V? Thanks for your help Kyran.

Comment: Because you are using less than 100mF, I would just got for any old Buck converter and a series resistor for the supercap to restrain it's ability to charge/discharge. Otherwise look at the supercap charger ICs available from Texas Instruments and Linear Technology, both have good simple ones which are essentially DC-DC converters with extra features like controllable input current limiting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22324/discussion-between-user2252031-and-kyranf).

Answer (score 2):

Consider putting the capacitor (along with its inrush limiting resistor and discharging diode) before the LDO. You probably want to run the whole lot from another diode to prevent it trying to drive the 24V supply.

Then you can use a lower value capacitor, because it can sag from 24V to somewhere around 5V before the LDO regulator starts to notice. Its voltage rating has to be higher, though, so I can't say whether there is an overall cost saving.

Comment: Would the trade off in package size from capacity versus voltage rating be worth it? I wonder what the size difference would be like.. also the huge cap would be wasting the difference in voltage while running the LDO, right at the time you do not want to be wasting energy. It's more efficient energy-wise for it to be on the output I suppose due to that